# Select and click option in combobox?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a combo box, once you select the item in the combo box, there's a second combo box that will insert data base on your selection in the first combo box. I'm not able to make that happen, only thing that happens is once i selected the item, my second combobox is not populated. Any ideas? Here's my code for selecting the item in the combo box:

```
var combobox= Ext.ComponentQuery.query('combobox[itemId=comboboxID]')[0];
combobox.select("item1", combobox);
```

Comment: You must have code somewhere for your second combo listening for the change event on the first combo, can you share that code too?

Answer (score 0):

On collapsing the first combo load the data into the store of the second:

```
combobox1.on('collapse', function(combo){
     var data = [/* ... */]; // the values for the second combo  
     combobox2.getStore().loadData(data)
})
```

Comment: there's two distinct values, let's say, first combo box is name, once selected, the second box will display the email associated with that name from the store.

Answer (score 0):

```
combobox1.on('select', function(combo){
     combobox2.setValue(combo.getValue());
})
```

Comment: there's two distinct values, let's say, first combo box is name, once selected, the second box will display the email associated with that name from the store.